# Getting parent directory from struct file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How do I get the parent directory for a `struct file*` in a linux kernel driver?

I want to get information about the parent, and the parents parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

the `dentry`, which I have been looking for was moved from beeing a direct child of `struct file` into `struct path`.

```
struct inode* parentDirInode(struct file* file) {
  return file->f_path.dentry->d_parent->d_inode;
}
```

still I hope that there is a better solution that does not break when they change the implementation structure. **Are there macros/functions I overlooked?**

Comment: You forgot locking and ordering.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko: could you either point me to a place where I can read up on this, or tell me which locks I need to take and what do you mean by ordering?

Comment: Only what I could recommend is to read the code. I meant RCU locking which is widely used in VFS and by ordering I meant CPU ordering, so you have to be sure that CPU will run commands in order you want, not CPU.